# Decode ReadableStream object nextjs 13 api route

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13

I'm sending a value to my server side code that isn't being read correctly. I'm using the NextJS experimental App directory

```
//src/app/api/auth/route.js

export async function POST(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { address } = req.body;
  const isAuthenticated = await checkBalance(address, threshold);
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return new Response("Authorized", { status: 200 });
  } else if (isAuthenticated == false) {
    return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
  } else if (isAuthenticated == undefined) {
    return new Response("Error", { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

console log is: `ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }`

const address is `undefined`.

This is the api call:

```
const response = await fetch("/api/auth", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ address: walletAddress }),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
```

I read in another answer to a similar question that nextjs12+ is supposed to parse the request automatically- what am I doing wrong? I'm assuming that nextjs has a protocol in place for decoding the ReadableStream but I can't find anything in the docs or examples for this, maybe because there is a framework agnostic method for decoding the object that is unknown to me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried doing `const { address } = JSON.parse(req.body);`

Comment: @inkredusk i've tried this, but it doesn't work:
```SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Rea"... is not valid JSON```

Comment: Not works in 13.4.1

Comment: @ReZ, try FahadAlAraik's answer, it works correctly for me- in general, you need to check if you are receiving a readable stream object and decoding it to json. I had an issue where I was making an api request to my server component, which made an api request to an external api. I couldn't retrieve the external api response without first decoding it in my server component and encoding it again before sending it client side. if you want to post a question, ill see if i can help

Comment: @Bigboss01 Thanks for the reply, but i solved my problem. I used typescript in my next aplication, so i got a type error because i didn't use the correct type. I was using ```NexApiRequest``` instead of ```NextRequest```.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've faced a similiar problem, you can try this:

```
const body = await req.json()
const {address} = body
// the rest of your code
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer doesn't address the case where you aren't receiving 'application/json'

Comment: is req can be json'ed, then what is its type?

Comment: Thanks for this! Super straight forward but not documented anywhere!

Answer (score 7):

you need to **await** the request from nextjs in order to get the body object.
Like the code bellow:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
    
    const body = await req.json();
    console.log(body);
    
    return NextResponse.json(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

```
...
const { address } = req.body
const isAuthenticated = await checkBalance(address, threshold);
...
```

Comment: oh sorry, that was an oversight- i fixed the code, it still returns undefined

Comment: I don't know why its returning a readable stream, maybe you should figure this out. But if you want to try actually reading the stream, check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Answer (score 0):

A discord user recommended `const address = await req.json();` instead of `const {address} = req.body` and it works.