# How can I make my Next.js API route to work?

Tags: next.js, app-router, next.js14, nextjs-api-router

I'm trying to write an API route using Vercel's documentation for days now and I just can't fix the errors. The documentation doesn't provide good enough examples. I'm using Next.js' app router which doesn't help at all, because the documentation provides even less support for that.

/app/events/page.js:

```
'use client'

import Flow from "./Flowchart";
import {subtitle, title} from "../../components/primitives"
import {Button} from "@nextui-org/react";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function EventPage() {

    const [eventName, setEventName] = useState('')
    const [event, setEvent] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/events', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ eventId: 1 })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(event => {
                setEvent(event);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching graph data:', error));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4 items-center custom-div"  >
            <h1 className={`${title()} `}>Workflow</h1><br></br>
            <h2 className={subtitle({class: "mt-4"})}>
                {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
                Upcoming events
            </h2>
            <div className="w-1/5">

                <Button
                    radius="lg"
                    color="success"
                    variant="ghost"
                    size="lg"
                    fullWidth
                    className="mb-4"
                    onPress={() => router.push('/login')}
                >
                    {event && event.name ? event.name : 'o0o'}
                </Button>
            </div>
            <Flow/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

/app/api/events/route.js:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return new Response('Method Not Allowed', {
            status: 405,
        });
    }

    const { eventId } = req.body;
    console.log(eventId)
    try {
        const event = await prisma.event.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: parseInt(eventId)
            },
            include: {
                nodes: true,
                edges: true
            }
        });

        // Return the retrieved data
        return res.json(event)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching graph data:', error);
        return new Response('Internal Server Error', {
            status: 500,
        });
    } finally {
        // Disconnect PrismaClient
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
}
```

Can you please help how to use the API routes with Next.js' app router?

With my current code is get the following error:

```
Error fetching graph data: PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.event.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: NaN
  },
  include: {
    nodes: true,
    edges: true
  }
}

Argument `in`: Invalid value provided. Expected ListIntFieldRefInput, provided (Null, Null, Null, Null).
    at Cn (C:\Stuff\clubinterflow\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:116:5888)
    at _n.handleRequestError (C:\Stuff\clubinterflow\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6510)
    at _n.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Stuff\clubinterflow\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6188)
    at _n.request (C:\Stuff\clubinterflow\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5896)
    at async l (C:\Stuff\clubinterflow\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:128:10871)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/events/route.js:18:23)
    at async C:\Stuff\clubinterflow\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591 {
  clientVersion: '5.10.2'
}
```

And eventId is undefined.

Comment: do you have more details on the content of the request as received in the api route?

Comment: @njzk2 it's a custom type called Event that has a name, a few fields and a nodes and an edges array. I use the nodes and edges to create a ReactFlow diagram from them.
additional information is if i don't use eventId in the request body and just write 1 to find the event, everything is working fine. i'm only having issues with passing the eventId.

Comment: I mean the `req` parameter to your `POST` function, can you log it or look at it in a debugger and confirm it looks like what you expect?

Comment: also why is your endpoint under `/app/api/events/route.js` rather than `/app/api/events.js`?

Comment: @njzk2 when i try to log `req`, i get this:
`ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }`
and `req.body` is undefined always.

i put the `route.js` in the `events` folder because i plan to make more API routes for my other pages. is it even possible with app router to write all api routes in the same `route.js` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode ReadableStream object nextjs 13 api route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899415/decode-readablestream-object-nextjs-13-api-route)

Answer (score 0):

as you are using app router, you have to get the body from `req.json()` instead of `req.body`. the `req.body` is only available in apis defined in `pages/api` folder.

Try,

```
 const { eventId } = await req.json();
```

You can read about this in the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#request-body)

Also, You cannot directly send `res.json()` in a route.js defined in app router, instead use [NextResponse.json()](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json)

Comment: i tried, but i still get an error: `⨯ SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: can u check the response by sending a req to `http://localhost:3000/api/events` by Postman or Thunder-Client? If you get a successful response, the issue is with calling the api from frontend